# Heroku nodejs application is not working

Tags: node.js, heroku

Below is a simple nodejs application which is working fine in the local but when I host the same in heroku with profile I am getting the error in the log

```
at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=fathomless-ocean-52301.herokuapp.com request_id=8403e46a-acf7-426a-bb58-1169546e9e8a fwd="103.5.132.3" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https

var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var app = express();

// Define the port to run on
app.set('port', (process.env.PORT || 1778));

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

// Listen for requests

app.listen(1778, '0.0.0.0', function() {
  console.log("... port %d in %s 1778 mode");
});
```

Please say how to run this or debug it

Comment: can you show your package.json content?

Answer (score 0):

change

`app.listen(1778, '0.0.0.0', function() {
  console.log("... port %d in %s 1778 mode");
});`

to

`app.listen(app.get('port'), function() {
  console.log("... port %d in %s 1778 mode");
});`

you should not use `1778` port.

Comment: same again no luck i was trying the same before

Comment: try to exec `heroku run bash`, then start your server in the new bash, see if it works on heroku env.

Answer (score 0):

You started server on defined 1778 port, what is wrong. Heroku suggest next code template

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var app = express();

// Define the port to run on
app.set('port', (process.env.PORT || 5000));

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

// Listen for set port
app.listen(app.get('port'), (err)=> {
    if(err){
        console.log("Error starting server");
        console.log(err);
        return
    }

    console.log("Server listening on port : "+app.get('port'));
});
```

Where node app port is set outside the app